# Spring Cloud Sleuth/Ziplin + Azure App Insight Integration

Tags: azure-application-insights, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am following below link for having distributed tracing in Azure App Insight-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/how-to-distributed-tracing?pivots=programming-language-java

I have provided the App Insight JavaAgent as well to my Java Apps. Now when I start my application I get the below error -

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: zipkin
```

Keeping in mind there is no Zipkin Server running. How can I resolve this error.

If I disable the Zipkin server using - `spring.zipkin.enabled=false`, would my traceId and spanId still go to the Aure App Insight.